# Python - Import module which is in a subfolder of a two level higher directory

Tags: python, import

Is there a **simple** and **robust** way to import a module which is in a subfolder (*Folder B*) of a two level higher directory (*Root*) in relation to the directory of the running script (*Folder A_2*)?

```
Root
--- __init__.py
--- Folder A_1
    --- __init__.py
    --- Folder A_2
        --- __init__.py
        --- Running_script.py
--- Folder B
    --- __init__.py
    --- target_module.py
```

Comment: If you import it like this `import B.target_module`, then run `cd Root` `PYTHONPATH=. python A_1/A_2/Running_script.py`, it should work. There are probably 10 to 200 different approaches you can take here.

Comment: Do you run the script as part of the ``Root`` package? I.e. do you execute this as ``python -m Root.A_1.A_2.Running_script`` or ``python Root/A_1/A_2/Running_script.py``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I start the script by left double clicking it

Answer (score -1):

I think all the directories with modules that you want to import must have an empty `__init__.py` file.
If you do so, Python will find it and you shouldn't need to specify any path. But check the link, it will explain it better.

You can check this out from [this link here](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/complete-guide-to-imports-in-python-absolute-relative-and-more/) for everything about imports.